# Could not execute the java executable while running Play 1.2.1

Tags: java, macos, playframework

I am facing this issue whenever I am trying to run Play 1.2.1 in my system .
Previously I had , Play2.0 in my system . 
I exported the PATH variable , so that PATH contains the path to Play 2.0 directory .

Now , I am trying to run Play 1.2.1 in Mac OS X 10.7.4 .

My PATH variable looks like ,

```
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0: No such file or directory
```

After exporting the PATH for play 1.2.1 my PATH looks like

```
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0:/Users/sabya/Downloads/Work/play-1.2.1: No such file or directory
```

I created a new project through `play new test_app` .

But whenever I am trying to do `play run` , its showing me

```
Could not execute the java executable, please make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set properly (the java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/java).
```

Typing javac/java in the same directory gives me proper output .

My $JAVA_HOME outputs `-bash: /Library/Java/Home: No such file or directory`

Everything working fine in Ubuntu .

What can be the work around at this situation ?
I have googled extensively . Did not get anything suitable .

Is the trailing ":" in JAVA_HOME a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, you seem to mix Play 1 and Play 2 in your path.

Also, JAVA_HOME should point to the directory where Java is installed in your system. I doubt that this `/Library/Java/Home` (try to open this directory with the Finder, and see if it exists).

Comment: Is there any problem in mixing Play 1 and 2 ?

Comment: both contains an executable named "play", so it will execute the first found; in your case the play 2.0 since it is the first in your path.

Comment: I tried removing the path for Play 2 using sed . It removed initially . But came back again . :(

Comment: it should be defined in some kind of `.profile` file in your home directory.

Comment: There is no .profile file in Mac. I have .bash_profile where I have some entries , like alias start_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start"
alias stop_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home

Comment: although, rename the "play" executable file in your play2 folder, in order to be sure that you use the play1 executable when you type "play"

Comment: Did that .. Same result though !

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `No such file or directory` message means that the specified path is incorrect, that it does not really exist. You might want to check that it was not (re)moved in the meantime, for example by issuing a simple `ls -al /Library/Java/Home`.

Comment: "You might want to check that it was not (re)moved in the meantime." -- Can you please clarify ?

Comment: java and javac are working fine even though there is "No such file or directory"

Comment: I suspect that the variable JAVA_HOME might have been defined in "/home/<user>/.profile" or "/home/<user>/.bashrc" where <user> is your username, but in the meantime someone removed the physical directory. java & javac are working fine because the 2 executables are included in the $PATH variable so bash knows where to find them. My suggestion is to either remove the faulty declaration or replace it with an existing path, such as "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java" if I'm not mistaking. After this you might need to re-login for the setting to take effect.

Comment: ls -al /Library/Java/Home gives me the ouput lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  48 Jun  4 00:40 /Library/Java/Home -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home

Comment: And `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home`?

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  24 Jun  4 00:40 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home -> Versions/CurrentJDK/Home

Comment: `ls -al Versions/CurrentJDK/Home` :) should issue a `No such file or directory`. You are using a chain of symbolic links which might point to a non existing directory.

Comment: Correct . Its No such file or directory

Comment: You could either try to find this so called "Versions/CurrentJDK/Home" and remake the links, or if java has been installed by apt-get/aptitude you should have a directory similar to mine "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java" and updating the JAVA_HOME variable to point to it could solve your problem.

Comment: In ubuntu I did it through apt-get and its fine. I am new to Mac and its giving huge pain to me whenever I am starting any new project with some new Framework. Mostly with PATH .

Comment: Not that familiar with mac, but since it's a unix distro it should be more or less the same as ubuntu, apart from the package manager. I think you could download a zipped jdk, extract it to some directory like `/opt/jdkx.y` and make $JAVA_HOME refer it. Some reboot or app relaunch might be needed after the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Grove . I will try to do some tweaks . Lets c whether it helps or not. Thanks by the way . :)

Comment: Heh, no worries, classpaths and paths for that matter, tend to take some time when you're setting your environment for the first time. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I set it long back and it was working well. After adding the new play 1.2.1 to the classpath , all got messed up ! Doh ! :(

Comment: Ehh stuff happens, what's important is accepting change as a normal thing and move on improving oneself ;)